# How to disable the lost network connection warning on OSX

Tags: macos

I'd like to permanently disable the warning dialog that shows when my Macbook loses connection to a network drive.  Is this possible in OSX Mavericks?

Answer (score 1):

From this article: http://whatsamknows.tumblr.com/post/37368603810/get-rid-of-server-connections-interrupted

The following steps should sort you out:

1. Click on the spotlight icon (magnifying glass) in the upper right of your screen
2. Type in ‘terminal’
3. Click the ‘Terminal’ icon (black with white border) under
   applications
4. Type in the following command and hit enter:
   `sudo mv /System/Library/LoginPlugins/FSDisconnect.loginPlugin /System`
5. It will prompt you for your user password. Type it and hit enter again
6. Reboot